# How to stop accepting new TCPStreams if I reach a number of clients connected has is over certain value

Tags: join, rust, tcp, rust-tokio, tcpserver

Hello I wan to limit the number of clients connected to my TCP tokio server. I have the following function to listen

```
async fn listen (connected_clients: Arc<Mutex<u8>>, tried_numbers:Arc<Mutex<Vec<u32>>>) {
   let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("localhost:8881").await.unwrap();
   *connected_clients.lock().unwrap()=0;
 
   loop{    
        //if *connected_clients.lock().unwrap() <=6{}  
        let (mut socket, _) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        let connected_clients = connected_clients.clone();
        let tried_numbers = tried_numbers.clone();
        *connected_clients.lock().unwrap()+=1;
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let (sread, _swrite) = socket.split();
            let reader = BufReader::new(sread);
            process_socket(connected_clients, tried_numbers, reader).await;
        });
        
    
   }
```

}

The problem is that if I wrap everything inside the condition to have less than 6 clients then it stalls everything done in data_printing because this is what I got in main:

```
 tokio::join!(
    listen(connected_clients,tried_numbers),
    data_printing(connected_clients2,tried_numbers2,total_unique_numbers,output_file)
);
```

so how can I do this?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not using `await` or related, so you never get back to `main` if you exceed, you just loop.  I recommend that in the case you exceed, you await on either `sleep` (the tokio version of it, not the normal one) or [`yield_now`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/index.html#yield_now).  To get both pieces to run, you need to `await` back, which you aren't doing with the mutex case.  But not putting this in an answer, because I have limited experience, and don't want to give out bad advice.

Comment: Related, doc on your [`join`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.join.html#runtime-characteristics) macro - you need to ensure `await` happens or else both do *not* happen.

Comment: @KevinAnderson you mean putting a sleep().await inside the loop but before the if condition?

Comment: Close.  If you never `await` then the 2nd branch of your `join!` never runs.  So put a sleep or yield when you detect that there's more than 6 clients, and then continue to the top of the loop again.